# Title of an image in vertical

Tags: graphics, titles

How can I place the title of an image vertically like in the figure?
[image]

Comment: You could have a look at rotatebox.

Comment: Are you sure the image wasn't rotated as well (as in sidewaysfigure or landscape)?

Comment: Yes the image is rotated with sidewaysfigure. But I want to write a title like in the figure and I don't know which is the command that I should use.

Comment: \centering\textsf{\Large Title}  would do it.  If you want a figure number, use \caption (see caption package for formatting options).  Just avoid packages like floatrow which move the captions.

Comment: The caption package also supports \caption* (no number).